# Subsetting data with amount of elements who meet a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, subset, subset-sum

Good morning. I would like to subset a data frame with the amount of elements which meet a certain condition. For instance:

```
COLOR   X    Y
RED     0    1
RED     0    1
WHITE   3    1
```

I'd like to have another dataframe with the amount of elements who have got the same X value and the same Y value, but I don't know how to build it.

```
COLOR   X    Y   AMOUNT
RED     0    1   2
WHITE   3    1   1
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: I just edited it. I'd like to have the amount of elements which have got the same X value and the same Y value, and have that amount as an attribute in the dataframe.

Comment: So you just want to count number of rows with same `COLOR` ,`X` and `Y` value? So in `dplyr`, you can do `df %>% count(COLOR, X, Y)`. Is that what you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(X, Y) %>% 
  mutate(AMOUNT = n()) %>% 
  distinct(X, Y, .keep_all = T)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   X, Y [2]
  COLOR     X     Y AMOUNT
  <chr> <int> <int>  <int>
1 RED       0     1      2
2 WHITE     3     1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.frame(df[!duplicated(df),],AMOUNT=as.vector(table(df$COLOR)))
```

gives,

```
  COLOR X Y AMOUNT
1   RED 0 1      2
3 WHITE 3 1      1
```

**Data:**

```
df  <- read.table(text="COLOR   X    Y
RED     0    1
RED     0    1
WHITE   3    1",header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```